# How to profiling a slow action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, benchmarking, profiler

I have an action costs about 10s:

```
Completed 200 OK in 9489ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 71.6ms)
```

I tried to wrap the whole action with `benchmark`:

```
def action
  self.class.benchmark("Processing projects") do
    blahblahblah...
    ...
    ...
  end
end
```

But it's report looks strange:

```
how long does it take (692.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9489ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 71.6ms)
```

I guess that the hidden 8.8s is in certain `before_filter` or something. But how could I find it? Is it possible to profile an action call at once?

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard to figure out which before-filters are running, why not just benchmark those?

Answer (score 2):

I'm watching a great video on this stuff.  at => [windy city rails](https://windycityrails.com/videos/2011/#2)

Also check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html

rails profiler and ruby-prof might help.  There are lots of good tools.  good luck

Comment: I tried ruby-prof, but how to set the session variables for it? My action need to be called by login users.

Comment: Your link to windy city rails is dead.